# Flat Assembler Binary

Tags: assembler

I am trying to compile a program using Flat Assembler (fasm) but I can't find a binary that works for the RPi.  I have tried the regular and  [arm versions](https://arm.flatassembler.net/) which both complain of "Exec Format Error".  Is there any such binary that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [`FASMARM`](https://arm.flatassembler.net/) is a cross-compiler to ARM (from x86), i.e. it allows a fasm installation on an x86 machine to compile to ARM machine code. While FASMARM can compile *to* ARM machine code, **it doesn't allow fasm itself to run on ARM.**

Since fasm is [written in Assembly](https://github.com/Konctantin/FASM), this makes porting it or compiling it for ARM challenging. I would not expect there to be a way for you to run fasm on your Pi.

You *might* be able to try compiling the code you have with a different assembler that is available on the Pi, but note that assembly is not always compatible between different assemblers. It may be wise to check the project's documentation and see if there is already a way to compile for the Pi, or ask a new question on this site otherwise.